# Unable to send email message through smtp server

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to generate an email using powershell script but failing to send an email as i encountered with below error, i have tried to check with various things to trail and check but i did not get the desired result

```
$emailbody = $body2
$from = "some@email.com"
$smtp = "smtp-au.domain.com"

Send-MailMessage `
    -From $from `
    -To "s.pap@domain.com" `
    -Subject "Scheduled Jobs Report Status" `
    -Priority High `
    -Body "$emailbody" `
    -BodyAsHtml `
    -SmtpServer $smtp
```

Comment: Do you know if authentication is required?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: If the usage of the `powershell-v2.0` tag is intentional you don't have that cmdlet available as it was introduced with [powershell-v3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Send-MailMessage?view=powershell-3.0)

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for your inputs it requires no authentication previously this code is used to work in my local machine but suddenly now i am facing this error, output message is displayed as Send-MailMessage : Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.3.2 Service not available

Comment: At line:4 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -From $from -To "username@domain.com"  -Subject "Engi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Answer (score 0):

try the following also use the ip of your smtp server not the fqdn

> [string]$stmp = 0.0.0.0
>
> [string]$emailfrom = email@company.com
>
> [string]$emailtoo = email@company.com (if you add more than one email address here add a [] at the end of string like so [string[]]$emailtoo)